# zephyr pin control on device tree

Tags: device-tree, pwm, zephyr-rtos

I'm trying to  create an overlay with for a pwm output for a pin in zephyr rtos , the overlay has pinctrl-1   and a pinctrl-name for pin configuration ,however  a .dts file was already define with with  pwm  pinctrl-0  and pinctrl-name ,the compilation fails with the error "device tree error : pinctrl-names ... expected 2 strings" , for pin control,  how can I resolve the issue ,  Thanks
Here is the exact error message I'm getting
"devicetree error: pinctrl-names property in /soc/pwm@40050000 in  has 1 strings, expected 2 strings"

Here is a section of the  the .overlay file  defining the pin control.

```
&pwm{
    pinctrl-1=<&servo>;
    pinctrl-names = "servo_pin";
    divider-int-0=<125>;
      status="okay";
};
```

Here is the  a section .dts file defining the pwm device tree

```
pwm: pwm@40050000 {
    /*....*/
    #pwm-cells = <3>;
    pinctrl-0 = <&pwm_ch4b_default>;
    pinctrl-names = "servo_pin";
    divider-int-0 = <125>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&servo>;
};
```

I wanted to edit the .dts file however it is advised not to edit configuration files the come as part of the zephyr library .
The issue  appears to be related to "pinctrl-names" is there a way to resolve the issue without editing the .dts file

Answer (score 0):

Provide 2 strings. For example:

```
pinctrl-names = "servo_pin", "idle";
```